# Custom open graph object properties being rendered in the post description on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm having a strange issue when publishing custom open graph stories.

I've got a custom action type "Create" and a custom object type "Task". I've also added a custom property to my Task object, called "extra_data". I'm using this to assign some JSON data to my object for reference in a mobile app when the action is loaded.

This seemed to be working fine previously, but now when I post an OG story to Facebook, the "extra_data" field is being rendered into the description box of the open graph story in the timeline.

I've attached an image of how this appears

[image: Custom object property being rendered in the OG story area]

Also its worth noting that this only happens on desktop browsers. In the Facebook mobile app the item looks correct.

Can anyone help identify why this might be happening?

Thanks!